# DNS-Python specific nameserver

Tags: python, dns, nameservers, dig, dnspython

i'm trying to figure out, how i can do the dig command

```
dig ns example.com @8.8.8.8              # example
```

in dnspython..

what I already tried is this:

```
res = dns.resolver.Resolver()           # also tried with configure=False
res.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

answer = res.query('example.com', 'NS')  # this raises NoAnswer
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Your python code works for me. Is your PC connected to the Internet? Does `dig` succeed on the same PC? Did **exactly** those three lines fail for you?

Comment: yes. pc is connected, dig works, and python code without specific nameservers works all fine.

Comment: Since the code the you've shared works correctly, perhaps the error is in the part you *didn't* share. Please post a short, complete program that demonstrates the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org for more info.